# Getting all the key and values from JCS Cache

Tags: java, caching, jcs

I'm using JCS cache. I want to retrieve all the keys and value from the specific region.

```
JCS jcsInstance=JCS.getInstance("regionName");
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Group Cache access class there is a method available called `getGroupKeys(String groupName)`.You can pass in the Group name and get all the keys in that group and iterate over it.

See the [documentation](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jcs/commons-jcs-core/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jcs/access/GroupCacheAccess.html#getGroupKeys-java.lang.String-) for more info.

Comment: I pass   Set<Integer> albumList = cache.getGroupKeys("musicCache"); but its showing me null